# Tkinter create_line problem: wrong # coordinates: expected an even number

Tags: python, tkinter

here goes my first ever question, im doing a basic logplayer from data in a txt file:

the code is something like:

```
    for aircraft in self.logArray.itervalues():

        for logLine in aircraft:
            currentPoint = self.point(logLine[1], logLine[2])
            currentPoint = self.win2canvas(currentPoint)
            points = np.append(points, currentPoint)

        print points
        print np.size(points)
        self.canvas.create_line(points)
        points = np.array([])
```

So  logArray is a dictionary, each name contains an array of kind [time,x,y], so there will be an array like that for each aircraft name.

The second for simply converts to tkinter canvas coords and appends the currentPoint to the pre-existing (and initialized).

When it gets to the create_line method, i get:

```
File "/home/joao/tese/workspace/ATC/src/autoATC/LogPlayer.py", line 131, in drawPath
self.canvas.create_line(points)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2204, in create_line
return self._create('line', args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2192, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected an even number, got 399
```

I've manually checked the size of the points array and is indeed even numbered. So i double-checked using  np.size, which returned 398!

I've also tried using a very similar test approach, doing:

```
    self.canvas.create_line([123,345,234,453,23,34,45,56,67,78])
```

which went perfectly!  I don't get why, but somehow my points array ends up getting an extra element, and I don't know where from!

Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: Even though it didn't answer the question, I managed to solve the problem:


I first tried to use the first 4 points of the point array, and still didn't work (it got 5 points).

What I forgot to consider (and also to mention) is that I am working with numpy arrays, so when I cast my points numpy array to a python list, like so:


        self.canvas.create_line(list(points))


the problem was solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you are using numpy arrays for this.  The call stack here looks like this

1. Tkinter.py,  line 2160, in
   create_line  return
   self._create('line', args, kw)
2. Tkinter.py,  line 2148, in _create
   *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
3. numeric.py,  line 1424, in array_str
   return array2string(a,
   max_line_width, precision,
   suppress_small, ' ', "", str)
4. arrayprint.py,  line 307, in
   array2string   return lst

If you have np.array([0., 0., 200., 100.]) the string that is returned by array2string() is **'[   0.    0.  100.  200.]'**.  I suspect that then it gets split returning the list of **['[', '0.', '0.', '100.', '200.]']** which has one extra element '['.

You code should work if you use a list in place of np.array() or even if you just cast the numpy array to a list, like:

```
self.canvas.create_line(list(points))
```

Although, I would think that using a list from the start is more straight forward if you don't need to use the functionality of numpy arrays.